# CSS Transition Problems in IE

Tags: html, css, list, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have a problem with **HTML** and **CSS**. So I have a **CSS** style for my list but in **IE** it doesn't work.

Here is my **HTML** file:

```
<ul class="main-ul2">
    <li><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Article</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Blog</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Gallery</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

And here is my **CSS** file:

```
.main-ul2 li {
    margin-left: 0;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:25%;
    text-align:center;
    }
.main-ul2 li a {

    display:block;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: rgba(164, 164, 164, 0.2);
    –ms-??transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
   -moz-transition: all 1s;
   -o-transition: all 1s;
   transition: all 1s;
}
.main-ul2 li a span{
   display:block;
   padding-top:10px;
   font-weight:700;
   font-size: 20px;
   color: rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.9);
   text-transform:uppercase;
   font-family: 'Kotta One', serif;

.main-ul2 li:hover span{
   color: #fff;
}

.main-ul2 li:nth-child(1):hover a{
background-color: rgba(175,54,55,0.8);
–ms-transform:rotate(-3deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
.main-ul2 li:nth-child(2):hover a{
   background-color: rgba(199, 204, 73, 0.8);
   –ms-transform:rotate(-3deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
   transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
.main-ul2 li:nth-child(3):hover a{
   background-color: rgba(213, 135, 11, 0.8);
   –ms-transform:rotate(3deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
   transform: rotate(3deg);
}
.main-ul2 li:nth-child(4):hover a{
   background-color: rgba(51, 143, 144, 0.8);
   –ms-transform:rotate(3deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
   transform: rotate(3deg);
}
```

So if you are using **Google Chrome** you can insert my code in [CCS Desk](http://cssdesk.com/7WJmJ) or any other online **CSS** editors and everything works fine (bullets are changing color and moving), but if you open my code in **IE** you'll see that it's not working fine.

I have search for it in **Google**, and I found that I need to add **Microsoft transform**.

So can someone tell me how can I add Microsoft transform or if there any other way to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition, IE 10 supports `transition`, so you don't need `–ms-??transition`

Comment: @MikeVayvala Perhaps the title of this post should be more specific. Because I could make a career out of studying web-consistency problems with IE.

Comment: Can we have the fiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE10 indicates that you can drop the `-ms-` prefix and use the base property. That said, I would continue to use it to support older browsers.

If you include the `-o-` and `-webkit-` you should be good to go with most recent browsers. `-moz-` is also available if you need to support old versions of Firefox.

If you really need to support old browsers (as far as IE6), you should probably utilize JavaScript because....well...anything before IE9 was pretty bad.

Comment: yes but, you can see that I wrote all of this prefixes in my css file and it still doesn't work fine

Comment: Your transition for `.main-ul2 li a` has -ms-??transition in it, which will cause it not to render